# penalty.factor with model matrix input

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to fit a model using glmnet. For the data input I am converting my data to sparse.model.matrix format using a model formula. I am trying to de-regularize one of the variables I wish to include as a control but I can not get the penalty.factor argument to work! First I am not sure how long the vector needs to be, the model matrix has columns for each level of my original variable, do i need to specify a penalty.factor for each level? I believe I have tried both, the longer penalty vector seems to do nothing while the shorter one results in an convergence error. The code is set up as below:

```
    X <- sparse.model.matrix(model.formula, data)
   fit <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(X, y, family = "poisson", type.multinomial = "ungrouped" , penalty.factor = reg.weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're on the right track. `penalty.factor` should be a vector the same length as there are columns in your sparse model matrix. In the example below, it would need to be length 8.

```
dim(X) 
[1] 32  8
```

If you're getting convergence issues, that's a separate problem unfortunately, and not necessarily related to the penalty.factor.